# While I go to submit data into Database table I face this error in browser console: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I am facing following in my react node project in login page .
So far I checked my code again and again after each execution but still the error shows.
I want to pass data into my mysql DB from login page. This is my first stage of my application.

```
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
```

Login.js File..

```
import React from "react";
import "./Login.css";
import jQuery from "jquery";
import { useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

const Login = () => {
  const [userNameReg, setUserNameReg] = useState("");
  const [emailReg, setEmailReg] = useState("");
  const [passReg, setPassReg] = useState("");

  const signup = () => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3000/login", {
      username: userNameReg,
      email: emailReg,
      password: passReg,
    }).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <section className="account">
        <div class="container" id="container">
          <div class="form-container sign-up-container">
            <form action="#">
              <h1>Create Account</h1>
              <div class="social-container">
                <a href="#" class="social">
                  <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="social">
                  <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="social">
                  <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
                </a>
              </div>
              <span>or use your email for registration</span>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Name"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setUserNameReg(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
              <input
                type="email"
                placeholder="Email"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setEmailReg(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
              <input
                type="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setPassReg(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
              <button onClick={signup}>Sign Up</button>
            </form>
          </div>
```

Server.js File

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  user: "root",
  host: "localhost",
  password: "",
  database: "MAKT",
});

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

  db.query(
    "INSERT INTO signup (name, email,password) VALUES (?,?,?)",
    [username, email, password],
    (err, result) => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );

  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Everything Okay......");
  });
});
```

See the follwing picture..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF6E1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your `app.listen` inside of your post route... so the server will only start listening for incoming connections when it receives a post request (which it can't do since it's not listening). Put the call outside the function.

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

  db.query(
    "INSERT INTO signup (name, email,password) VALUES (?,?,?)",
    [username, email, password],
    (err, result) => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
});
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Everything Okay......");
  });
```

Comment: outside of the function, I actually can not catch your suggestion please put precise explanation

Comment: `app.listen` is inside of `app.post`. You need it outside like the code I put shows

Comment: If this solution helped you please mark it as correct by hitting the checkmark so others can find it :)

Comment: yes still I'm working on that after finalize I'll make it tick